# Returning multiple calls to methods from another method in JavaScript revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, callback, module-pattern

I am experimenting with the revealing module pattern for a current project.

I have *init* methods at the top of several methods where i set up variables and call methods necessarry for the modules to function correctly when they are called by their appropriate event handlers.

I have a *init* method that looks like this currently:

```
function init(elem) {
    var width, 
    height,  
    tipHeight, 
    tipWidth, 
    topMargin, 
    leftMargin;

    return appendTip();
};
```

So this returns a call to the appendTip method.

In another module the set up looks like this:

```
    function init() {
        var width = 0,
        $siteNavListElem = $('.nav-SiteNav .nav-list > li'),
        $subNav = $('.subNav > li > ul');

            appendSubNav();
        getWidth();
};
```

So now there are two calls to individual methods.  This code works fine but wondered if it could be any neater?

How do i return both of these?  Is returning them the best way to call them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I am not sure if you are following the revealing module pattern at all. The pattern explains returning a public object that contains the public interface of your object. So returning a function from within a function doesn't really constitute that pattern. For that pattern you are looking at doing something like this

```
 function revealingPattern = function(){
    var privateVar = 1;
    function prviateFunction(){
    //.....
    }

    function publicFunction(){
    //code
    }

    function pubFunction2()[
    //code
    }
    var publicVariable = 2;

    return{
     pubFunction1:publicFunction
    ,pubFunction2:pubFunction2
    ,pubVariable:publicVariable
    };
    }()

//use as
revealingPattern.pubFunction1();
```

Basically all you are returning from the encapsulating function (revealingPattern) is an anonymous object that contains named properties which are the public interface of the revealingPattern object that you are allowed to use.

My gripe with this pattern however is that it doesn't tell you whether a property in the returned object is a function or a variable!

So you might want to refactor your code a bit if you really want to implement the pattern. Otherwise you can pretty much take any approach you would like. They are all valid but just not the revealing module pattern.

Comment: My reference material was this: http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript

Comment: If you scroll down to the The Revealing Module Pattern section.

Comment: I just went through the link. Actually even there it is described that in this pattern, the key thing is to return an anonymous object that contains the pointers to your public functions. The "return" statement that returns {set:setPerson,get:getPerson} is doing that. So basically you don't return a function call as return myFunction() but an anonymous object that contains a "reference" to the function as return {myFun:myFunction}. Hope this explains a bit

Comment: Yes i see your point.  Am unsure then how to perform the 'init' tasks needed on page load

Comment: Do you absolutely need this pattern? I mean are there methods or properties that you want to "hide" from your script? That pattern will enable you to create an "object" essentially with a public interface you can use and a private interface that you can not use. If that is not something you want, you can skip the entire pattern and simply do what you are already doing in your second code sample. Alternatively post more details and some code and I shall help you out :)

Comment: I would agree that the pattern may be overkill for my current purposes but what attracted me was being able to make my code modular.  I like the idea of privacy as well so thought i would give it a go.  It is not working code but the full module is here: http://jsfiddle.net/yCMUs/1/  I really wanted to stop my code being coupled to events.  So in my example it is teied to a hover event.  But it could be used somewhere else more easily following this pattern.

Comment: I also got the idea for the helpers from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339668/how-can-i-safely-access-other-sibling-functions-and-variables-in-a-javascript-mod

Comment: Also when i review this http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html#chapter-10 they appear to be performing similar actions by calling private methods from within other methods.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do there. I must say the temptation to delve into the pattern is quite strong! However I would be a bit concerned when you have a statement like icisSite.tooltip = function(elem){....this effectively says you can create a singleton object (your icisSite.tooltip one) by defining a function and calling it immediately (by doing a }() at the end) because your function depends on an argument which must be passed! I am not suggesting you should not use the pattern or the neat syntax, just that you (or we!) should find an approach better suited to your needs.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I don't know how to remove the dependancy on the passing the element that is hovered to the module though.  I need to know which one is being hovered so as to show the correct tooltip.  I guess plugin architecture would be more appropriate here?  I know there are many tooltip plugins already rolled out there but i am against loading in resources we do not need and also wanted to roll my own :)  I find this is teaching me much more than just inspecting others code.

Comment: I am having a play around with a custom pattern. Once I am done I shall post it for you to see. You have to promise to not laugh though :)